# WSO2 EMM - blacklist application

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

Is it possible to define white list instead of blacklist in wso2_emm and just lock other apps when device connected to enterprise network?
How can I modify wso2_emm to do this?

client devices are android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current implementation, you can not achieve that. You can always try digging into the code and improve. It's in our official documentation[1].

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/WSO2+Enterprise+Mobility+Manager

Thanks